# Exluding an Inner Child Element with XPath?

Tags: dom, xpath

Please consider the following structure:

```
<Table>
    <TR>
        <TD>
            <Table>
                <TD></TD>
            </Table>
        </TD>
        <TD>Value 1</TD>
        <TD>Value 2</TD>
        <TD>Value 3</TD>
        <TD></TD>
   </TR>
</Table>
```

I want to get a list of the `<TD>` nodes, but only if it does not have a child node (or if it doesn't have a child named 'table' in this specific example). I tried to filter the extra `<TD><TABLE>` nodes by using the `not` options - `//table/tr[not(td/table)]` but I'm getting an empty object. The end results should be an list with 4 `<TD>` object (value 1 to 3 and the empty one below). How can I do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can select `<td>` elements that doesn't have child `<table>` as follow :

```
//table/tr/td[not(table)]
```

but you can't select `<tr>` element, excluding that particlar `<td>` which contains `<table>`. XPath only capable of selecting part that exists in the source XML. In particular, there is no such `<tr>` element that contains only 4 `<td>`s in your XML.

Comment: I see, I didn't know it's not possible. So whats my other options would be? programmatically not parse this specific node?

Comment: Find the target `<tr>`, then programmatically find all `<td>` with child `<table>` within the `<tr>` and remove them..